# How to Add Data to a CollectionView for Just the Newly Append Index from an array Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hey I'm trying to figure out. After I append a string to the array that is the collection views data reference. How do i just/only reload that latest string/ index recently append the the array and not the whole collection view

Ok so I know so far this reloads all which will cycle through all index in the datasource / Array of Strings :

```
log.reloadData()
```

So I append the string:

```
// collectionViewDataSource is a UICollectionView

var collectionViewDataSource = [String]()

collectionViewDataSource.append("new string")
```

Reload:

```
// now to figure out how to update the view for just that index and not complete reload every cell, but just add a new cell 

log.reloadItems(at: <#T##[IndexPath]#>)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to determine the index path of the newly added data. In your case it's trivial. Use the count of the array before adding the new object.

```
let newIndexPath = IndexPath(item: collectionViewDataSource.count, section: 0)
collectionViewDataSource.append("new string")
collectionView.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath])
```

Note that you need to insert a new item into the collection view, not reload one.

Comment: Thanks, You know your like a legend on here. You Answer a lot of questions